# How to skip subscribe result?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an stream changes$ that emits data:

```
interface Data {
  id: number,
  prop: string
}
```

This stream is switched by another that makes http request.

In the end I subscribe to response:

```
.subscribe((response =>apply() );
```

How dont call apply() method if before getting response from last request a new data were emitted to initial stream?

Because despite http request was sent the data is outdated, cause source stream changes$ emits a new data.

Comment: Can you share the whole code (whole `pipe`line)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel previous requests and only fire the latest request with redux observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160430/cancel-previous-requests-and-only-fire-the-latest-request-with-redux-observable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right the question, what you are looking for is something like this

- the process starts with `changes$` emitting a value of type Data
- once a Data instance is emitted by `change$` then an http request is fired, probably with that instance of Data as parameter but this is not relevant in this case
- once the response of the http request is received, the `apply` function is executed, probably with the response received as parameter but again this is not relevant
- BUT if, before having received the response from http, another instance of Data is emitted by `change$`, then the previous http request is cancelled and we just wait for the result of the second request before calling `apply`

If this is all true, then the operator you are looking for is `switchMap` which does unsubscribe any previous subscription to its inner observable (i.e. it cancel any http request on fly in this case) and starts a new subscription any time it receives a new notification from the upstream Observable.

The code would look like this

```
change$.pipe(
   switchMap(data => fireHttpRequest(data)),
).subscribe(
   response => apply(response)
)
```